# Ошибка создания docker образа PHP при установке зависимостей

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Делаю Docerfile для php

Содержимое и список зависимостей на которых падает build

```
FROM php:8-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER root

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libzip-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    nano \
    ruby \
    ruby-dev \
    zsh \
    automake \
    mariadb-client \
    software-properties-common \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    make \
    rsync \
    fzf \
    sudo \
    whois \
    ntp \
```

выполняю команду `docker-compose build app`, и раньше образ собирался без проблем.

Спустя 4 месяца вернулся к проекту, снова выполняю `docker-compose build app`

но теперь получаю ошибку

```
[+] Building 4.4s (7/23)                                                                                                                                                                                       
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:8-fpm                                                                                                                                              1.0s
 => [ 1/19] FROM docker.io/library/php:8-fpm@sha256:533977625839b1ba6a281ca77dd5ee77e9b16d2341c617818582e99b97ad7dd7                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 99B                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/19] WORKDIR /var/www                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => ERROR [ 3/19] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y     build-essential     libpng-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libfreetype6-dev     locales     zip     jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle    3.3s
------
 > [ 3/19] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y     build-essential     libpng-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libfreetype6-dev     locales     zip     jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle     vim     unzip     git     curl     libzip-dev     libonig-dev     nano     ruby     ruby-dev     zsh     automake     mariadb-client     software-properties-common     gcc     g++     make     rsync     fzf     sudo     whois     ntp RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mysqli mbstring zip exif pcntl:
#0 0.285 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [116 kB]
#0 0.416 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [48.4 kB]
#0 0.486 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [44.1 kB]
#0 0.547 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 Packages [8072 kB]
#0 1.966 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main arm64 Packages [218 kB]
#0 1.994 Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main arm64 Packages [12.0 kB]
#0 2.593 Fetched 8510 kB in 2s (3486 kB/s)
#0 2.593 Reading package lists...
#0 2.867 Reading package lists...
#0 3.150 Building dependency tree...
#0 3.214 Reading state information...
#0 3.265 E: Unable to locate package RUN
#0 3.265 E: Unable to locate package docker-php-ext-install
#0 3.265 E: Unable to locate package pdo_mysql
#0 3.265 E: Unable to locate package mysqli
#0 3.265 E: Unable to locate package mbstring
#0 3.265 E: Unable to locate package pcntl
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y     build-essential     libpng-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libfreetype6-dev     locales     zip     jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle     vim     unzip     git     curl     libzip-dev     libonig-dev     nano     ruby     ruby-dev     zsh     automake     mariadb-client     software-properties-common     gcc     g++     make     rsync     fzf     sudo     whois     ntp RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mysqli mbstring zip exif pcntl]: exit code: 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте удалить `\` в конце строки `ntp \`. Этот символ позволяет создавать команды состоящие из нескольких строк, в вашем случае это перечисление пакетов , которые нужно установить, то последний `\` лишний, т.к. он приводит к тому, что следующая строка в `Dockerfile`: `RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mysqli mbstring zip exif pcntl` распознается не как команда докеру, а как часть `apt-get`, про что и говорится в ошибке.